# Why is IE8 rendering superfish menu wrong?

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8, superfish

I am useing the superfish jquery plugin

If you view the superfish menu here: [clicky](http://www.kranichs.com/layout2010/index2.php)

the drop-downs show correctly (above the main content) in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, IE6, IE7

But for some reason they fall behind the main content in IE8.

I already set the z-index for the superfish menu which IE7 wasnt working right until I did so, but it didn't fix IE8.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine in IE8 when I remove the

```
overflow: hidden
```

in ie.css: `#header_container #nav_container`.

Why this works in IE7, I don't understand, though - it would mean 7 ignores the `hidden`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure your menu sizes are all matching, IE: the UL width needs to be all the same, mine is 14 so i made all the menus be 14 and that fixed the issue in ie.

Answer (score 0):

The superfish FAQ points you to this [blog page](http://webdemar.com/webdesign/superfish-jquery-menu-ie-z-index-bug/) which fixes the problem by putting z-indexes onto the **relative** divs you are using e.g. #header and #content.